# Automatic JavaScript code indentation in VS 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

In spite of having web essential & productive power tool installed for Visual Studio 2012, javascript code with in aspx page doesn't indent automatically.

This is how I type:

```
for (var i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
}
```

This is how I want to indent:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
}
```

I am not sure which extension for VS 2012 used to do it on my older PC. The moment I type, end curly brace, it will indent my javascript code automatically. I did look at settings but didn't get it right

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: By "didn't get it right" do you mean you didn't find the settings or you did but it didn't work?

Comment: If I go by features, it is stated that VS 2012 or web essential take care of indentation but it is not working. I am not  sure if I had any other extension which was doing that for me.

Answer (score 1):

try `Tools | Options | Text Editor| Javascript | Formatting | New Lines` gives you the option to put an open brace on a new line.  Uncheck that option and see if that works.

Comment: Try `Tools | Options | Text Editor | File Extension` and register the file type you are working on as script editor